# How can I "bind" a key combination to start a Windows 8 application?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

Is it possible to assign shortcut keys to windows 8 applications? For instance, I want calendar to be easily accessible so that i can just press one key or a combination like WINDOWS+C and it shows me the calendar.

In windows 7, there used to be things called Gadgets which allow me to just peek through the desktop and see the calendar.

(Hopefully, without using third party applications like AHK.)

Comment: @Karan this question is regarding using Windows hotkeys to run applications, not an actual shortcut link.  I edited the question to clarify this better.

Comment: @Breakthrough: Once a shortcut is created assigning a keyboard shortcut to it is trivial (as per Andre's answer below). The OP's restriction against 3rd party apps like AHK means that Win-key shortcuts aren't possible, so that leaves us with keyboard shortcuts associated with actual shortcuts. Unless perhaps you know of an alternate solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is not direct solution to your question but hope this help.

If you have short cut to your program you can right click and check the properties. There is a field to assign keyboard short cut to your exe or program.

[check this link for more information](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4999-shortcuts-assign-keyboard-shortcut-windows-8-a.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use this [script to generate shortcuts to the Store Apps](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Open-Windows-Store-apps-569de170).

Now follow the guide from Eightforums to assign a keyboard combination to the shortcut.